# Pandas left merge on a specific column with a DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge those two dataframes in order to replace in the left one values that are present in the right one with the same ticker and datetime.

Here is a small example

[image: Left dataframe]

[image: Right dataframe]

[image: Result dataframe]

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Kindly do not post pictures. Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Add Company as an index level then this is [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
# update uses index matching
left_df = left_df.set_index('Timestamp')
right_df = right_df.set_index('Timestamp')

# update does inplace modification, so returns nothing.
left_df.update(right_df)

print(left_df)
```